violates foreign key constraint (SQLSTATE 23503)
i face this error when trying to generate my comment attach to the topics:
fail to create comments, err=error while scanning created comment IDs, err=ERROR: insert or update on table "comments" violates foreign key constraint "comments_topic_id_fkey" (SQLSTATE 23503
this is my comment_dao.go
func (d CommentDAO) Create(comments ...dto.Comment) ([]dto.Comment, error) {
    if len(comments) == 0 {
        return nil, nil
    }
    
    query := d.genInsertSQL(len(comments))
    var args []any
    for _, c := range comments {
        args = append(args, c.By, c.TopicID, c.Content, time.Now())
    }
    
    res, err := d.db.Query(query, args...)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, fmt.Errorf("fail to create comments: %w", err)
    }
    
    ids := make([]int, 0, len(comments))
    for res.Next() {
        var id int
        if err = res.Scan(&id); err != nil {
            return nil, fmt.Errorf("fail to scan for created comment ID: %w", err)
        }
        ids = append(ids, id)
    }

    if err = res.Err(); err != nil {
        return nil, fmt.Errorf("error while scanning created comment IDs, err=%w", err)
    }

    for i, c := range comments {
        c.ID = ids[i]
    }

    return comments, nil
}

func (d CommentDAO) genInsertSQL(numComments int) string {
    var sb strings.Builder
    sb.WriteString(`insert into msg_board.comments(by, topic_id, content, created_at) values `)
    genSQLParams(numComments, &sb, 4)
    sb.WriteString(` returning id;`)
    return sb.String()
}

my seed.go to run generate
const numUsers = 10



func genTopics(db *sql.DB, users []dto.User) ([]dto.Topic, error) {
    const minTopic = 2
    const maxTopic = 5

    topics := make([]dto.Topic, 0, len(users)*minTopic)
    now := time.Now()

    for _, u := range users {
        n := randInt(minTopic, maxTopic)
        for i := 0; i < n; i++ {
            topics = append(topics, dto.Topic{
                By:    u.ID,
                Title: fmt.Sprintf("topic %d by user %d at %d", i+1, u.ID, now.Unix()),
                Body:  "random string at " + now.String(),
            })
        }
    }

    d := dao.NewTopicDAO(db)
    createdTopics, err := d.Create(topics...)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }

    if len(createdTopics) == 0 {
        return nil, fmt.Errorf("no topics created")
    }

    log.Printf("Created topics: %v", createdTopics)
    return createdTopics, nil
}



func genComments(db *sql.DB, users []dto.User, topics []dto.Topic) {
    const minComments = 1
    const maxComments = 5

    comments := make([]dto.Comment, 0, len(topics)*maxComments)
    now := time.Now()

    for _, topic := range topics {
        log.Printf("Creating comments for topic ID: %d", topic.ID)
        n := randInt(minComments, maxComments)
        for i := 0; i < n; i++ {
            user := users[rand.Intn(len(users))]
            comment := dto.Comment{
                By:        user.ID,
                TopicID:   topic.ID,
                Content:   fmt.Sprintf("Comment %d by user %d on topic %d", i+1, user.ID, topic.ID),
                CreatedAt: now,
            }
            comments = append(comments, comment)
        }
    }

    d := dao.NewCommentDAO(db)
    createdComments, err := d.Create(comments...)
    if err != nil {
        log.Printf("fail to create comments, err=%v", err)
    } else {
        log.Printf("created comments: %v", createdComments)
    }
}

func randInt(min, max int) int {
    return rand.Int()%(max-min) + min
}

this is my dto.go


type Topic struct {
    ID        int       json:"id,omitempty"
    CreatedAt time.Time json:"created_at"

    By           int    json:"by,omitempty"
    Title        string json:"title,omitempty"
    Body         string json:"body,omitempty"
    CommentCount int    json:"comment_count,omitempty"
    Upvotes      int    json:"upvotes,omitempty"
}

type Comment struct {
    ID        int       json:"id,omitempty"
    CreatedAt time.Time json:"created_at"

    By      int    json:"by,omitempty"
    Content string json:"content,omitempty"
    TopicID int    json:"topic_id,omitempty"
} ```   

 I have try to catching error logs, fix the dto but it not work


In the comment you're trying to insert, there's a topicId that doesn't exist in the topic table.

i thought i was insert the topic id due to schemas.sql, here is my schema
(
    id         serial primary key,
    by         integer references msg_board.users (id),
    content    text not null,
    topic_id   integer references msg_board.topics (id),
    created_at timestamp with time zone
);```
